# Executing a perl script in php with a link

Tags: php

I want to execute a perl script from a php file. This perl script have to be executed with the click on
     tag. For e.g:

```
<a href="?????">Run now</a>
```

Can anyone tell me how to give link and execute a perl script ? Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `exec` php function.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

In this case, the target of your link will be a simple php script :

```
//simpleScript.php

<?php
    exec("/path/to/your/perl/script.pl");

    // + error and output handling. It depends of your script
    // + other actions, return, redirect ...
```

And in your HTML :

```
<a href="path/to/your/php/simpleScript.php">Run now</a>
```

Comment: Thank You.. Can you give me an e.g of how to use both anchor tag and exec function?

Comment: Thank you so much.. I have written code correctly, even though exec function is not working.

Comment: exec, shell_exec, system, all those functions probably blocked by your server provider. see `phpinfo();`

Comment: I checked whether exec function is enable using function_exists('exec'), it is giving that exec is enabled. There is no mention about exec in phpinfo() page.